# How to switch companies in iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect

My itunes connect account is linked to 2 independent companies for which we develop apps. When I log in to itune connect, I can only access one company and not the second one.

How can I switch between companies?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, you should not mix one Apple ID with two companies.
You should have one Apple ID per company so you can manage profiles and access information correctly. This way, you will have problems, but they will be solvable e.g. your profiles do not refresh correctly. Then you may remove all the profiles in the Organizer and download the ones for the company you are currently working (you select that via your Apple ID e-mail address).

I had problems when I tried mixing different companies into one Apple ID.

Best regards!